# Include comment at top of webpack file

Tags: webpack

I'm using webpack to bundle a bunch of javascript files together, and I need to include a copyright notice at the top of the file. I can't seem to figure out how to do that, or if it is possible.

The closest I've come is to use the raw loader, but that hides the copyright in an exported function. Any idea.

Something that is cross-platform is preferred.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use the webpack [BannerPlugin](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/). With this plugin you can add any string you want at the top of your bundled file.

I have used it to add some package name, version, license, and other info at the top of a [library of my own](https://github.com/dreyescat/react-rating/blob/v0.1.0/webpack.config.js#L58).

### webpack.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  // Other stuff
  plugins: [
    new webpack.BannerPlugin('Your copyright notice')
  ]
};
```

Comment: updated link: https://webpack.js.org/plugins/banner-plugin/#root

Comment: The BannerPlugin doesn't work in production mode if you're adding raw comments, like in a UserScript. Instead, it adds `/*! For license information please see .min.user.js.LICENSE.txt */`.

Comment: I was able to manually add a comment both at the end and at the beginning of my bundle file using the technique outlined here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-cli/issues/312#issuecomment-732749280