# Append comment to all source maps with webpack

Tags: webpack, source-maps

The answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34280117/include-comment-at-top-of-webpack-file) using BannerPlugin works for my bundle.js and css files but I also have source maps available in production that I would also like to comment.

Is there a way to include the BannerPlugin along with the source-map-loader?

```
module.exports = {
...
devtool: "source-map",

module: {
preLoaders: [
            { test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
        ]
    },
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work using webpack-append

```
loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "ts-loader"
            },
            {
                test: /\.tsx?$/,
                loader: "webpack-append",
                query: '// oh hi there'
            },
      ...
]
```